# Как осуществить проверку логина и пароля из базы данных в SQLite WindowsForm на C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Мне нужно, чтобы после нажатия кнопки войти программа проверяла логин и пароль пользователя сохраненные в базе данных.

```
class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set;  }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
}
 class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
public partial class FormAuth : Form
{
    UserContext db;
    public FormAuth()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db = new UserContext();
        
    }

    

    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxLogin.Clear();
        textBoxPass.Clear();
    }

    private void buttonAuth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.Login = textBoxLogin.Text;
        user.Password = textBoxPass.Text;
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void buttonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        FormMain showForm = new FormMain();
        showForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Где здесь кнопка "Войти", надо догадаться? Нужно больше потробностей. Что надо - вы рассказали, а что не именно не получается - нет. `db.Users.Any(x => x.Login == textBoxLogin.Text && x.Password == textBoxPass.Text);`?

Comment: Кстати, для тех кто хранит в базе пароли в открытом виде, в аду есть отдельный котёл. Не устану это повторять. Используйте хэширование.

Comment: Кнопка войти здесь buttonEnter. Я не знаю как правильно организовать проверку логина и пароля. Нужно ли создавать отдельный метод? Если нужно, то как он должен выглядеть? И мне нужно использовать хэширование SHA1.

Comment: То что я выше написал, это и есть проверка, засуньте в условие if.

Comment: Хэш любой подойдет, хоть MD5, это лучше, чем открытый пароль. Но я бы [PBKDF2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) использовал, [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes) или [SHA256](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256).